# Ionic 2 - Read a .wav file and convert it to base 64

Tags: angular, audio, ionic2

I want to send a audio file to a Webservice.
My problem is that I am realy struggling to get my file.wav in a base64.
I have to read the file from my phone and convert it to base64.
I just found JS examples and I am struggling to understand them.
I know that I am able to use btoa(MyVariable) to make my base64.
I Would mainly ask for help to get the date from a local file in a Variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to read a file you can just use the http.get() function:
    `this.http.get(URL)`
    `.subscribe(res => this.data = res.text());`

then you have the file as text but not base64.

**Maybe someone has an idea how to convert that res.text() to a valid base64 string?**